# clone() a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to replicate a div with jquery but my code doesn't work.

```
var replicate = function () {
    var i=0
    while (i<200) {
        $(".square").clone().appendTo("content2");
        i++;
    };
};
```

tell me please where I am wrong, and also if there another way doing this.

Comment: The second selector should be the culprit. By the way, your code can torture the browser.

Comment: There are no elements in HTML with tag name `content2`.

Comment: i forgot the "#" sorry ^^

Comment: Please post the Html that goes with this and I can tell you why it is not working.

Comment: Also please be more specific about how your code is not working. Do you have javascript errors  in the console ? Are any divs being appended at all ?

Comment: I only forgot the '#', thank you!

Comment: You should get a dramatic increase in performance if you cache the clone first.

Comment: Actually, you miss the "#" before content2.